# Character Encoding Error When Running rake assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, character-encoding, sass, asset-pipeline

I have a rails app that is getting a weird error when I try to run `rake assets:precompile`. It looks like this:

```
rake aborted!
Invalid US-ASCII character "\xE2"
  (in /Users/lee/Code/draper/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)
(sass):9
```

I'm not sure where an invalid character might have slipped into my code. I'm using Twitter Bootstrap (boostrap-sass gem) and my `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss` file seems to be the culprit. I've already tried recreating this file from scratch in text mate to get any weird characters out and that didn't work. The only thing that seems to work is adding this to the top of my `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss`:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

That allows me to run rake assets:precompile and then deploy to Heroku, but that seems like a hack and a dirty fix. I can deploy other apps to Heroku that use bootstrap-sass just fine and Heroku is able to run rake assets:precompile when deploying. Right now the only way to get around it is to include the `@charset "UTF-8";` and then run `rake assets:precompile` locally before deploying to Heroku so that it skips that step during deployment.

I can't figure out where I went wrong with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your CSS files. The character `\xE2` usually correlates to a double quote character that's not part of the ASCII character set. In an editor they often look like a more slanted double quote. `“mystring”` vs `"mystring"`

Using the `@charset` declaration isn't a hack, but if you don't need to be using a UTF-8 character, you're probably better off removing it.

Comment: This was indeed the problem. This is the first place I've found that mentioned \xE2 might be related to a double quote. That hint enabled me to find the problem and it was indeed a slanted double quote that was causing all the issues. Once I removed that I was able to also remove the @charset declaration and everything worked fine. Thanks so much!

Comment: Well the file isn't even UTF-8 if `\xe2` is a quote.

Comment: Upvoting simply because searching for funny double quotes saved me hours of additional headaches after hours of headaches. Mine was erroring out on rake db:migrate. Thanks, Marc!

Answer (score 2):

Declaring correct encoding for your file is not a hack, a text file always needs a declared encoding and physical encoding. Anyways, you could just remove all non-ascii characters with iconv on the file:

```
iconv -t ASCII//IGNORE -f UTF8 < application.css.scss > application.css.scss.ascii
```

Then the resulting file will work with virtually any encoding.

Comment: I guess I was thinking it was a hack to have to declare it in my css file because Rails sets the encoding in config/application.rb with `config.encoding = "utf-8"`

Comment: Yes that was a helpful way to clean the file up. I was trying to do it by hand previously and had not found the character causing the problems.